# Errors when compiling LightBend "The Eventual PlayFramework-AngularJS-Bootstrap-MongoDB Seed Project" template

Tags: playframework, sbt, typesafe

Have tried to get the "The Eventual PlayFramework-AngularJS-Bootstrap-MongoDB Seed Project" working from:

1. IntelliJ 2017.1 EAP | New Project | Scala | Activator ......
2. Terminal with Activator new ..... eventual
3. activator ui - select "The Eventual PlayFramework-AngularJS-Bootstrap-MongoDB Seed Project"

All throw errors about:

> unresolved dependency: play#sbt-plugin;2.1.5: not found
>       sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: play#sbt-plugin;2.1.5: not found

I'm using latest version of "**typesafe-activator**"

```
usr/local/Cellar/typesafe-activator/1.3.12
```

Has anyone got it running, if so what are the changes required?

Answer (score 0):

Compiles and starts for me (with "activator new .." on the command line), without changes. Maybe a temporary problem with the repository where the plug-in is hosted?

Also, please be aware that this example is a few years old, Scala 2.9, Play 2.1.5, that's all very outdated. Unfortunately quite a few activator templates have not been kept up-to-date after they were published, so you might want to look for a more recent example.